# scala futures and fallbackTo

Tags: scala

I'm reading up on the use of futures and fallbackTo on the following page:

[scala docs on futures](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)

and I'm not seeing the behaviour I'm expecting.

I have the following test (taken from the page and slightly modified):

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.util._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val usdQuote = future {
    sys.error("1")
    "20.0"
} map {
    usd => "Value: " + usd + "$"
}
val chfQuote = future {
    sys.error("2")
    "15.0"
} map {
    chf => "Value: " + chf + "CHF"
}
val anyQuote = usdQuote fallbackTo chfQuote
anyQuote onSuccess { case s => println(s) }
anyQuote onFailure { case t => println("error ... " + t) }
```

I've been playing with commenting/uncommenting the sys.error() calls in the quote futures. Having no sys.error's gives me the output of "Value: 20$". Enabling the first sys.error() gives me "Value: 15CHF". So far so good, however when I enable the second sys.error(), as I understand it, it should give me the exception of the first future, i.e. "error ... 1", but it gives me "error ... 2".

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Marc.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation seems to be inconsistent with the implementation.

I have taken these snippets from scala v2.10.3

```
// In Future.scala
def fallbackTo[U](that: Future[U]): Future[U] = {
   val p = Promise[U]()

   onComplete {
      case s @ Success(_) => p complete s // first future succeeded
      case _ => p completeWith that // first future failed, complete promise with second 
   }
   p.future
}

// In Promise.scala
final def completeWith(other: Future[T]): this.type = {
  other onComplete { this complete _ } // complete the promise with second future's result
  this
}
```

We can see that the promise is completed with either the success of first or success/failure of second future.

So if both futures fail, we get failure of second future.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug in the implementation, see this issue:

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6913